# How to draw text  fitting in a given rectangle on a canvas?

Tags: javascript, text, canvas, drawing

I am creating some images using the canvas. I would like to be able to draw text in given rect (i.e. offset x, offset y, width and height) on a canvas and that text to be as large as possible without overflowing and if possible, with word wrapping. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible.

1. no-wrapping:
   You can use `CanvasRenderingContext2D.measureText()` method, which accepts a string, and returns a object { width: float }. You have to find out the height by doing some math using font's size. Then just enumerate the font sizes in a binary search way. soon you will find the best size for the canvas.
2. wrapping:
   You have to find out the wrapping point in the string and calculate their width and height you self.

but there is a better easier way to do this.

create a hidden(visibility: hidden not display: none) div, defines its width, and put your text inside. enumerates font's size, and check if it overflows or grows too high.